# How to connect my VNC server without opening the port 5901?

Tags: port-forwarding, amazon-ec2, vncserver, security-groups, tigervnc

I have installed and configured VNC server on Amazon EC2 instance. But the port 5901 is not opened in my security group. Is there any way to connect my VNC server from Windows without opening the port 5901?

Answer (score 0):

The ususal way to do this is to use an SSH tunnel, typically running on port 22. If your VNC client doen't have an option for that, you can use `putty` (or better the scriptable companion `plink`).

Comment: Could you please provide me some links to do this SSH tunnel.

Comment: Assuming you are using `PuTTY`, its in the docs. In short: Do a port-forward of local localhost:something to remote localhost:5901, then point your VNC client to localhost:something